# Efficient way to make sure file is (X levels)? under a certain directory

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I need to make sure a certain file is inside (doesn't matter how many levels) a certain directory.

To visualize:

```
A/ + file
```

or

```
A/ + x/x/x/..../file
```

It has to be under A, doesn't matter how many levels.

The file path (after the plus sign) is given to the program by the user.

The thing is that I can't use chroot, because the program also needs to access some folders outside A (lets say B) but users (that are connected via socket interface) should not be able to access them via `A/ + ../B/file`

This will be done in an inner inner loop so it has to perform well. I have thought of counting '/', extracting number of '..', extracting number of '/./' and comparing it >= 1 but it both does not perform well and feels open to bugs since the input is given by the user.

Is there a function that checks this that I don't know of or some other way?

EDIT:

If there is a way that will grant me access to folder **B** even after I chroot (file handles remain after chroot if I remember right, I need folder version of that), that is also OK. All I need is to access **B**, create/read/write files in it after the chroot.

EDIT2:

By the way, I know a way to do this using UID and such but I need an alternative.

Comment: is `A/` always the root of the path?

Comment: @WhozCraig A is just a randomly placed folder if you are asking that. It can be /A, it can be /home/X/A or anything. However A is in the working directory of the program.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was asking.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `path.find("/A/") < path.find("/progname")`...

Comment: @H2CO3 you mean "/workingdir"? chdir is used to go some unrelated directory in main(). Yet, "/progname" is not even in the path. The path is a relative path to an arbitrary file. I couldn't understand.

Comment: @Tolga I don't understand that. Now do you need to check if the file is under A or working dir? (And no, if I write A, I **mean** A...)

Comment: @H2CO3 I asked if /progname was /workingdir, not A, because I don't understand where /progname came from, it is not in the question, it doesn't matter where the program is running or what name it has, it is not in the path, either.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And what if the user does `ln -s A/foo /etc` and then uses `A/foo/blah.txt` to your program.

Comment: @MatsPetersson User doesn't have access to that, user sends requests via socket interface and the program does some calculations and responds accordingly. I need to make sure user doesn't go to places it does not have access to, yet the program needs to be able to use other folders myself.

Comment: One approach is to `fork`, open the files you need outside `A/.../`, then call `chroot`.  The parent process won't be affected.

Comment: Another method might be `seteuid`.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem with the first one is that files will be created outside 'A' for cache purposes so I constantly need access to specific 'directories' outside 'A'. Is there a version that I can open a folder and access files to it after chroot? Does opendir(3) do that, remain and give access after chroot? I couldn't find information about that use case.

Comment: @Tolga: If you `opendir` before `chroot`, you can still use the handle after `chroot`.  But all you can do with it is read the directory listing, it doesn't give you any access to files inside the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to append the user-supplied path string to end of the A directory's path, and then use the POSIX [realpath()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/realpath.html) function to simplify the resulting path string.  (realpath() will iron out any ".." or symlink shenanigans and give you a simple,  absolute file-path string)

Then compare that path to the A directory's simplified/absolute path.  If the file-path string starts with A's path-string (e.g. strncmp(file_path_str, a_dir_path_str, strlen(a_dir_path_str))==0), then allow access to the file; otherwise deny access.

Comment: Nice way, marking as the answer. Still better solutions are welcome though.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `ftw()` or `nftw()`  in a recursive function.

While doing this, you need to make sure that you do not follow symlinks or limit the traversal to them.

Initial start may scan the frequently visited folders for memoization until a request is received and while the system is idle. All requests are added to the memoization (hashtable etc.)

You can find the details [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "user" doesn't have free access to the system, but has sufficient privileges in itself, I'd expect that [`chroot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man2/chroot.2.html) is the solution you are looking for.

So, instead of validating the directory structure of the input, simply change the "root" so that it points at "A/" - and then (if need be) remove "A/" from the start of the path, and accept the rest.

Comment: But the program also needs to access "B", yet prevent access to it to user in case (s)he used '/../' or something like that. chroot inside 'A' is not the solution unless I find a way to constant access to B, which is outside the jail, after I chroot.

Comment: Can you open the file in B before you open the file in A? If so, use `fork` to `chroot` after you have opened the file in `B`. Or, make files in `B` readonly [assuming you don't need to edit them], make A and B live in a common directory that only has A and B in it, and `chroot` to the common level.

Comment: There isn't 'the' file in B unfortunately. I need to access arbitrary number of files in B and also create files in B for further caching.
A and B are in a common directory and I am currently chrooting to that common directory like you said. But I need to prevent access to B from user queries, which are essentially relative file paths.

Comment: Ok, I give up. Can't come up with a solution that works for that scenario. Not sure there is one.

Comment: Maybe I should give it up for a while too, it seems like I am stuck with the same approach to this problem.

Comment: Of course, one solution is simply to not allow reduntant/non-canonical paths. That is, you are not allowed to use "./" or "../" in the path at all - that would solve all these issues. Just check if the string contains "/../" or "/./" (and possibly if the string starts with "../" or "./".

Comment: The user also needs to be able to use '../' but just not outside A.